# Увеличение числа на 0.1 jquery

Tags: html, jquery, float

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при изменении количества бывают числа с 10 знаками после запятой?

```js
function plus_modifier_count_product() {
  var count = parseFloat($("#amount").val());
  var new_count = count + 0.1;
  $("#amount").val(new_count);
}

function minus_modifier_count_product() {
  var count = parseFloat($("#amount").val());
  var new_count = count - 0.1;
  $("#amount").val(new_count);
}
```

```css
.modifier_count {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modifier_count" onclick="minus_modifier_count_product();">-</div>
<input type="number" id="amount" placeholder="Количество" value="1.5" step="0.1">
<div class="modifier_count" onclick="plus_modifier_count_product();">+</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function plus_modifier_count_product() {
  var count = parseFloat($("#amount").val());
  var new_count = count + 0.1;
  $("#amount").val(Number(new_count.toFixed(3)));
}

function minus_modifier_count_product() {
  var count = parseFloat($("#amount").val());
  var new_count = count - 0.1;
  $("#amount").val(Number(new_count.toFixed(3)));
}
```

```css
.modifier_count {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modifier_count" onclick="minus_modifier_count_product();">-</div>
<input type="number" id="amount" placeholder="Количество" value="1.5" step="0.1">
<div class="modifier_count" onclick="plus_modifier_count_product();">+</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в JavaScript есть проблема потери точности при операциях с дробными числами. Подробнее об этом написано [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/number#netochnye-vychisleniya).

> Можно ли обойти проблему? Конечно, наиболее надёжный способ — это округлить результат используя метод toFixed(n)